# Cannot find Account Name Field in Dataloader.io while trying to Update Opportunity Account Name

Tags: data-loader, account, field-update, dataloader.io

I cannot locate the Account Name field within DataLoader.io in order to change the account of about 270 opportunities:

[image]

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose Account ID
then choose lookup to select Account Name

[image]